# Missing usbhid driver. 18.04 kernel 5.4.0-1040-azure

Tags: 18.04, drivers, usbhid

*USB keyboard and mouse* not working as driver is not present.

```
# uname -r
5.4.0-1040-azure

# modprobe usbhid
modprobe: FATAL: Module usbhid not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1040-azure

# ls /lib/modules/5.4.0-1040-azure/kernel/drivers/hid
hid-asus.ko     hid-hyperv.ko  hid.ko          hid-maltron.ko  hid-redragon.ko       hid-steam.ko      hid-wiimote.ko
hid-cougar.ko   hid-ite.ko     hid-led.ko      hid-mf.ko       hid-sensor-custom.ko  hid-udraw-ps3.ko  intel-ish-hid
hid-generic.ko  hid-jabra.ko   hid-macally.ko  hid-nti.ko      hid-sensor-hub.ko     hid-viewsonic.ko  uhid.ko

# apt list --installed | egrep '^linux'|grep "$(uname -r)"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-headers-5.4.0-1040-azure/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.4.0-1040.42~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.4.0-1040-azure/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.4.0-1040.42~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-5.4.0-1040-azure/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.4.0-1040.42~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1040-azure/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.4.0-1040.42~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-tools-5.4.0-1040-azure/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.4.0-1040.42~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I've reinstalled `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1040-azure` without success, any suggestions?

Comment: Suggest you add the make and model of the computer, keyboard and mouse to the question

Comment: If I boot with the 4.15.0-136-generic kernel which includes the 
usbhid driver, I can use the keyboard & mouse.

HP Z2 SFF G4 Workstation (4FU30AV)
HP USB Optical Mouse
HP USB Business Slim Keyboard

Comment: Kernel modules are definitely not something I’m knowledgeable about. However in the following link, just under the examples heading there appears to be a way to use a link to point to and install the module. Since you have this for the generic kernel perhaps you can add it to those available for the azure kernel. (Replace the Uname part with the path to the generic kernel) https://www.computerhope.com/unix/modprobe.htm. Just an idea. However I do wonder why you want to run a kernel designed for an azure platform on a desktop? You don’t have to answer that, I’m just curious :)